# Python if statement always returns false, even though input is true

Tags: python, if-statement

So I'm writing a program (A sort of "custom if statement") that checks if your input is true or false. This is the script I have right now:

```
v=line[3:] # Remove "if " from the line, so you only have the question and the consequence
i=v.split(': ') # Make a list with the first item being the question and the second item being the consequence.
for r in i:
    if r==i[1]: # Check which item in the list is the question and which is the consequence
        c=r
        question=i[0]
        consequences=c.split(' | ')
    for x in consequences:
        self.consequences+=f'\n{x}' # Create a variable with all of the consequences, each in one line
    Answer=False # reate the Answer variable with the default value False
    def checkVal(question):
        global Answer
        if question:
            b=open('if.BaRT','w+')
            b.write(self.consequences)
            b.close()
            self.run('if.BaRT')
            os.remove('if.BaRT')
        else:
            pass # Check if the question is true or false
    if Answer==True:
        print("True!")
    else:
        print("False!") # Finally check if the question is true or not and if it is, print "True!" and if it's not, print "False!"
```

I'm expecting this to work, but then when i input something that's true, for example: `__name__=="__main__"`, so my input looks like this:

```
if __name__=="__main__": print("Hello!")
```

this is the output:

```
False!
```

How do I fix this so it prints it accurately?

Comment: Is Answer ever being updated?

Comment: Using `exec` is something that you should avoid unless you're doing something very specific that forces you to do so. Here, it's almost certainly a bad idea, and you should find a cleaner way to rewrite your code...

Comment: @AlexWalczak Yes, the answer is updated in the `exec()` function. If there's anything wrong with it, please tell me.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille That's what I'm trying to do, but I just don't know how. That's why I asked this question

Comment: Then you should clarify what this piece of code is supposed to do, and provide some well chosen sample input data and the expected output.

Comment: I will edit it so it will hopefully be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: consequences added

I have replaced your exec with eval to get rid of your global variable (still not good coding practise, but if this is what you need...). Also, the for is not needed.

PS: the variables i, v and c should have better names.

```
line='if __name__=="__main__": print("Hello!")'
v=line[3:] # Remove "if " from the line, so you only have the question and the consequence
i=v.split(': ') # Make a list with the first item being the question and the second item being the consequence.

c=i[1]
question=i[0]
consequences=c.split(' | ')

_consequences=''
for x in consequences:
   _consequences+=f'\n{x}' 
Answer=eval(f"{question}") # Check if the question is true or false

if Answer==True:
  exec(  _consequences)
  print("True!")
else:
  print("False!") # Finally check if the question is true or not and if it is, print "True!" and if it's not, print "False!"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it. Also, I am not good at writing clean code at all. I'm working on it tho. But again, thank you for helping me.